# Laravel - Guzzle 7 : How get effective url in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I want to get a link from user and check it , if it redirects , we take the last url ( final redirected url )
for example if this links : goo.gl/test/123 redirects to the google.com , we take the http://google.com
in Guzlle`s old versions we can get effective url , but in version 7 I didnt found any way to get this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi 
 You can do sth like it

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['allow_redirects' => ['track_redirects' => true]]);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://test.com');
```

If you want to read more about the "track_redirects" look at [this link](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#allow-redirects)

Comment: This answer is a bit incomplete and could probably be improved by adding the information, see "Provide context for links" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 2):

The write Answer for list of redirected / just one url :

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['allow_redirects' => ['track_redirects' => true]]);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'shorturl.at/jvOS5');
$lastRedirect = $response->getHeaderLine('X-Guzzle-Redirect-History');
```

More in Document : https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/7.0/faq.html?highlight=redirected#how-can-i-track-redirected-requests